# How to print the elements of a hockey stick in a pascal triangle in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

The starting row number and the length of the hockey stick will be taken as input. We need to print the elements of the hockey stick excluding the sum.

The following code prints the pascal triangle with 10 rows(row:0 to row:9). How to add code to get the elements of the hockey stick?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int l, r, arr[10][10];
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if((i==j)||(j==0))
            {
                arr[i][j] = 1;
                cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i][j] = arr[i-1][j-1]+arr[i-1][j];
                cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


 return 0;
}
```

It gives the output as below,

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Now we need to take starting row and length of hockey stick, 
let's take 
starting row-3
length-4

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
**1** 3 3 1
1 **4** 6 4 1
1 5 **10** 10 5 1
1 6 15 **20** 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

sow hockey stick formation will be like,

1+4+10+20 = 35

We need to print the final output as below,

```
1+4+10+20
```

Note: No need to print the sum element-35

=================================
I have added the code as below,

```
cout <<"enter starting row-\n";
cin >> r;
cout << "enter length of hockey stick-\n";
cin >> l;
cout << "\nelements of hockey stick-\n";

int j=0;
for (int i=r; i<=(r+l-1); i++)
{
    int j = i-r;
    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Got output as -

```
enter starting row-
3
enter length of hockey stick
4

elements of hockey stick-
1 4 10 20
```

But I need it to be as below.

```
1+4+10+20
```

Comment: It shoudn't be hard, given that you already generated the triangle. Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have added the code I tried to print the elements in description, thanks!

Comment: So what's the problem? Replace whitespace with `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint of HolyBlackCat is in general right...

...except that the last element would be suffixed by `+` as well.

That's why I would recommend to turn it around: prefix every element except the first with `+`. This is achieved with an initial separator string which is empty. It is overridden at end of loop:

```
const char *sep = "";
//int j=0; // unused
for (int i=r; i<=(r+l-1); i++)
{
    int j = i-r;
    cout << sep << arr[i][j];
    sep = " + ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Note:

The assignment of `sep` in loop might be unnecessary for every than the first iteration. AFAIK, this is usually cheaper than an extra `if` test.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks!! I am printing the pascal triangle in a right angle format, so basically I am not giving any space before the 1st column element. In other websites, the pascal triangle looks different. In that case they are giving space before printing, how can we print in that way?

Comment: @JayS 1st) print all digits with max. num of needed characters (in your sample 3, or better 4 to get spacing for free). 2nd) you have to manage an indentation count which depends on number of lines and is decremented for each row resp. Output of indentation is probably very simple: If `int indent` is you indentation value just `cout << setw(indent) << ""` at begin of each row. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f6709a8a3f81673)